# Angular 6 - Tour of Heroes - prevent adding hero with existing name

Tags: angular

Angular tour of heroes: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/stackblitz
how to prevent the user to add a hero with an existing name? I would like to show an error message that name already exist as well.

Comment: To answer the question that was asked, use a custom `ValidatorFn`.

Comment: You'd either have to have a service that returns a `409 Conflict` Status Code and then based on that you could show the user a validation error using an `async` custom validator

Answer (score 0):

Just check for hero names from HeroService and don't push the new hero if the names match.

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => {
  // Check if some of the heroes already has that name
  if (heroes.some(hero => hero.name === name)) {
    alert('Hero already exists!');
  } else { // If not, do as you already did
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
  }
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvjevg?file=src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts